# Wordpress, posts as navigation with content changing

Tags: wordpress, navigation, posts

is there a way to show the posts like this: [link](http://www.videomarathon.dk/)

(go to "Om videomarathon" and then click "jury"

I need to show the posts as a navigation with the only the content changing and the navigation being fixed. (like on this page)
Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Any form of "tabbed" javascript would do that providing you have appropriate markup in the post itself. All you would be doing is hiding everything except the year you want to view.

jQuery would be one fairly easy way of implementing it (you may be loading jQuery on the page anyway). [jQuery Tabs Demo](http://jqueryui.com/demos/tabs/)

Comment: I figured it out by playing around with single.php pages etc. Thanks anyway :-)